# Ubuntu 20.04 - Bridge KVM

Tags: 20.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 and `libvirt` for virtualization. The default bridge works well with NAT and I am able to establish internet connections.

With a bridge to have a VM on the same network, I cannot go beyond the server.

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not go beyond the server." ? Show us what you have done, and what your configuration is.

Comment: With the default bridge (DHCP and NAT server), I can join a web host on the Internet. With the bridge for the same network (my network behind the router is 192.168.1.0/24), I cannot join the internet network. I can ping the host providing the guest. Hosts outside of the hypervisor do not connect to the client. Guest IP is not reachable. I have also deactivated selinux and emptied the iptables rules and also set the card in promiscuous mode. I took several tutorials but nothing helped. This is a new motherboard for Ryzen 7 5700G with B550 chip which I updated to the latest firmware.